# drupal custom filter module - replacement patterns

Tags: regex, drupal, filter

I migrated site from phpBB to D7 and attachments didn't go through. They are included in the forum body. I have bbcode filter in place. Want to change all instances of `[attachment]` to `[img]` and add php to include correct path. The module that does that is [customfilter](https://drupal.org/node/210555).

My example:

Replace

```
[attachment]photo.jpg[/attachment]
```

with

```
[img]http://example.com/files/images/photo.jpg[/img]
```

I don't understand regular expressions and patterns seem to not like the `[]` brackets.

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: Do you have attachments that are not images? Also, I see that this is your first post here. Please read the guidelines for asking questions - its always best to provide specific example input, expected output, what you've tried etc.

Answer (score 0):

I can't help you with your URL fixup problem but I can with the following...

### Matching square brackets with a regex

Inside a regular expression, square brackets: `[]` are *metacharacters* (used to define a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)). To match a square bracket (or any other regex metacharacter) in the target string you need to escape it with a backslash inside the regex pattern. Thus to match: `[tag]`, the pattern needs to be: `\[tag\]`. (Actually the closing square bracket is technically not a metacharacter, but I like to escape it anyway - which does no harm and better conveys the meaning that we intend to match a literal: `]`.)

### PHP function: `attachment2img()`

The following tested PHP function converts all: `[attachment]file.jpg[/attachment]` tags to: `[img]file.jpg[/img]` tags. Note that this function only changes attachment tags having contents ending in: `.jpg`, `.jpeg`, `.gif` and `.png` (to limit them to image files only).

```php
function attachment2img($text) {
    return preg_replace('%
        # Match a [attachment]image.jpg[/attachment] construct.
        \[attachment\]     # ATTACHMENT open tag.
        (                  # $1: ATTACHMENT contents.
          [^[\]]+          # Image URL up to extension.
          \.               # Extension separated with a dot.
          (?:              # Group of allowed image extensions:
            jpe?g          # Either a .jpg or .jpeg,
          | gif            # or a .gif,
          | png            # or a .png extension.
          )                # End group of allowed image extensions.
        )                  # End $1: ATTACHMENT contents.
        \[/attachment\]    # ATTACHMENT close tag.
        %ix', '[img]$1[/img]', $text);
}
```

The above regex is written in free-spang mode and is fully commented (note the: 'x' flag modifier at the end of the pattern string). All non-trivial regexes should be written this way to improve readability and maintainability.

**Example input:**

```
These should match:
stuff [attachment]simplefile.jpg[/attachment] more stuff.
stuff [attachment]relative/path/file.jpeg[/attachment] more stuff.
stuff [attachment]http://domain.com/path/file.gif[/attachment] more stuff.
These should NOT match:
stuff [attachment]file.zip[/attachment] more stuff.
stuff [attachment]file_jpg[/attachment] more stuff.
stuff [attachment]file.jpg.txt[/attachment] more stuff.
stuff [attachment]file.nonimage[/attachment] more stuff.
```

**Example output:**

```
These should match:
stuff [img]simplefile.jpg[/img] more stuff.
stuff [img]relative/path/file.jpeg[/img] more stuff.
stuff [img]http://domain.com/path/file.gif[/img] more stuff.
These should NOT match:
stuff [attachment]file.zip[/attachment] more stuff.
stuff [attachment]file_jpg[/attachment] more stuff.
stuff [attachment]file.jpg.txt[/attachment] more stuff.
stuff [attachment]file.nonimage[/attachment] more stuff.
```

Hopefully this will give you a head start.